# How to connect self made wooden structure to metal bike frame

Tags: wood, metal

I have a bike with an extended frame in the back, being able to accommodate two small children. For this back section of the bike, I built a custom rain cover, for which I constructed a simple wooden frame.

This wooden frame can be imagined as four polls connected to each other at the top, and on the bottom, resting on the metal bike frame (like a small roof), creating 4 contact points with it. The wood polls are 2cm wide (0.787402 inches), the metal frame around 1.5cm (0.59 inches)

The question:
How do I connect this wooden "roof" to the metal frame?

Ideally, I don't want change the metal frame too much (so drilling a few holes is fine, but no soldering).

Things I thought about:

- drilling a hole in the polls and put zip ties on: not strong enough, tends to move around
- drilling a hole in the frame and connect with wood using metal plates (having holes): also feels like it might move around when windy

Comment: I believe the saying is, "A picture is worth 1000 words". You're asking how to attach a homemade thing to an uncommon bike structure, but provide no picture at all. The best we can do is throw random guesses at you. _Please_ [edit] your question to include pics of the bike (including close ups of the area you'd like to mount the structure to) and the structure you're mounting to it (including close ups of the bike connection area).

Answer (score 1):

Use some small [U Bolts](https://www.screwfix.com/p/rawlplug-bright-zinc-plated-steel-u-bolt-m6-x-48mm/3283R?tc=TC4&ds_kid=92700048793290424&ds_rl=1249413&gclid=CjwKCAiAheacBhB8EiwAItVO2xvJ-79NJBxcsRh6i3-QUDzwHXsToh-sKr2CNrpDMptwtOkMykVPmhoCGB4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) like these to bolt the wood to the frame.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use some longer than necessary [Jubilee style hose clips](https://www.on1shelf.com/diy-fixings-c32/hose-clamps-c34/jubilee-original-range-mild-steel-hose-pipe-clips-zinc-plated-p2846) to fasten to the tube frame of the bike.

[image]

You could then drill a hole or two through the end of the strap like I have just done on this old one.  You could then screw this to your wooden frame.  Add as many clips as necessary to give a firm joint.

[image]